# How to list the functions / symbols contained inside a dynamic library in mac os?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, osx-leopard

How to list the functions / symbols contained inside a dynamic library in mac os ?

I need to see the list of function exported by a dynamic library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [How to export symbols from a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756174/how-to-export-symbols-from-a-shared-library) and [How do i find out what all symbols are exported from a shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237575/how-do-i-find-out-what-all-symbols-are-exported-from-a-shared-object)

Also checkout `nm` http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/nm.html

Comment: this isn't an answer, just links to other articles.

Comment: and what if those links disappear in the future? At least put a basic example of how to use nm.

Comment: Stack overflow links should be stable. Referencing existing question is completely valid. I'm not going to reproduce the man pages for nm. Sorry.

Comment: The OP was asking specifically about dynamic libraries in macOS. The answers in the two SO links do not cover macOS dynamic libraries.

The link to the nm man page is the GNU version, which differs from the macOS version.

Answer (score 17):

See [`nm(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html), something like `nm -gU <your lib>`.